# Testing snapshot deployment of a gradle plugin under construction

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I am just starting out creating a plugin for our build system. My plugin has one task that prints a message.  I am able to publish a snapshot of this plugin to our artifactory snapshot folder and my first usage of it from a test build file works.  However, subsequent publishing of an updated snapshot of the plugin fails to get pulled into my test build (it is cached).  I can bump the revision of the snapshot, publish the new version, and this works (defeats the cache), but that kind of defeats the purpose of the snapshot no?  I've seen a few posts about defeating the cache of a specific dependency by adding:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}
```

and setting the 'changing' attribute on my plugin dependency:

```
dependencies {
    classpath ('org.my.gradle:my-gradle-plugins:1.0.7-SNAPSHOT') {
        changing = true
    }
}
```

None of these settings has any effect.  The plugin remains cached.  I certainly don't want to blow away the entire cache and bumping the revision works but I'd really prefer not to have to do this while I'm coding the plugin as it is somewhat labor intensive.

Ideas?

Comment: [Solved by Benjamin Muschko on gradle forums.](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/testing-snapshot-deployment-of-a-plugin-under-construction/20264/2?u=bill_pfeiffer).  The quick answer is to add the resolution strategy into the buildscript block within the configuration.classpath block.

Answer (score 0):

The [solution](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/testing-snapshot-deployment-of-a-plugin-under-construction/20264/2?u=bill_pfeiffer) is to move the resolutionStrategy into the buildscript block:

```
buildscript.configurations.classpath {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}
```

Credit to [Benjamin Muschko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/528428/benjamin-muschko) for this [solution](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/testing-snapshot-deployment-of-a-plugin-under-construction/20264/2?u=bill_pfeiffer)